# Is it possible to extract a sublist from a C# linked list?

Tags: c#, linked-list, sublist

I'd like to get a sublist from a linked list in c# to keep track of its values. The problem is that if you simply create a linked list with the relevant nodes, the start and end nodes lose their links to their respective `Previous` and `Next` properties. This means that I can't go back and forth using the sublist to traverse the original linked list.

If one of the lists (original or sublist) receives a new node, this must reflect in all copies. If a reference changes, this must also reflect in all copies.

[image]

Is there an existing type in c# which I can use for this purpose, or will I have to write my own version of a linked list and linked list nodes that always keep their references? Or is there perhaps an even better data structure for this purpose (not necessarily already in c#)?

Comment: So you want a sublist such as [2, 3, 4] but you want 2 to point back to 1, and 5 to point forward to 5?

Comment: What would happen if you inserted a "5.5"?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to populate the sublist with all the elements of the original list by scrolling back or forth given some fixed number of elements shown.

Comment: And what should happen if I changed the yellow "4"? Would all "4"s get changed? Or is it a copy?

Comment: @TheGeneral that's true, but the `Previous` and `Next` properties are read-only and when you create a new linked list, the first element loses its reference to `Previous` and the last element loses its reference to `Next` as they are set to `null`.

Comment: @nvoigt the numbers indicate the index of each element, not necessarily the value of the element in the linked list, and I think the value should change for all lists (including the original) if one value is changed.

Comment: @JansthcirlU I know. My questions remain the same. What should happen if you insert between 4 and 5? What happens if the value at position 4 changes, do all values at position 4 change, or just that one?

Comment: There is not enough information here.

Comment: @nvoigt in that case yes, all copies of 4 should get a `Next` to 5.5 and all copies of 5 should get a `Previous` to 5.5

Comment: What kind of information would be useful here?

Comment: So basically you don't want copies, you just want a marked range in your list?

Comment: I have never heard of that term, but I guess so?

Comment: You mention references, but you also have value types (numbers), which affect semantics. What purpose does this data structure have, how will you use it? Looks like you don't need these "sublists" at all, because if you use `linkedList.Next.Next` you have the start of your sublist?

Comment: @CodeCaster the idea is that I have one linked list which contains chronological data, and by extracting sublists I could take snapshots of the data from different points in time. If I have multiple sublists I can re-run the data output however and whenever I want.

Comment: Do you need "sublists" for that, or just a starting node? What you want to do functionally doesn't have to be reflected exactly like that in code.

Comment: @CodeCaster I figured I'd like to do data binding, so yes, I would like to get a collection rather than boundary nodes

Answer (score 0):

There is no such class, but you could easily write one yourself:

```
class LinkedListRange<T>
{
    LinkedListNode<T> Start { get; set; }
    LinkedListNode<T> End { get; set; }
}
```

Add as many convenience methods as neccessary. Maybe a `Parent` Property if you are passing around the original list anyway. Or a `Next` methods that checks whether the next node is actually still in range.

Comment: But you can't modify the list using nodes, you need the containing LinkedList for that (AddBefore/After and so on).

Comment: I see, so this way you don't technically make a new linked list so the `Start` and `End` nodes retain their references to `Previous` and `Next`, right? I guess the answer wasn't as complicated as I thought it would be. Let me give it a shot and I'll return with my findings later.

Comment: @CodeCaster I guess then we do need the `Parent` property I talked about :)

Comment: Actually, I've run into an issue. If I want to use data binding to the content of the list's range, I'd have to keep querying through the parent to subtract a collection that can be bound to. So, I guess I'll have to make my own linked list after all.